# Imagining basis vectors in XY coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have just started learning Linear Algebra and in Vectors there is this concept of standard basis vectors , î and j, and all the vectors can be expressed as the sum of these two basis vectors. I want to know if any two random vectors can also serve as basis vectors ? What is the intuition behind this ?

Comment: Any two *linearly independent* vectors in a plane can serve as a basis. (Basically this means: none of them is the zero-vector and they are not collinear.)

Comment: Welcome. You should investigate the term *linearly independent*. Any two, linearly independent, vectors will form a basis of the “XY coordinate system” (the Cartesian plane, i.e. $\Bbb R^2$). For intuition, I highly recommend “3blue1brown”’s YouTube video on *span*

Comment: And, imagine two such vectors, bring them to a common origin and draw the $x$ and $y$ axis in their directions - you will get a coordinate system. Those two axes may well end up *not perpendicular* to each other, but that is not a problem.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Wouldn't any two points in $R^2$ be collinear? I actually just started learning axiomatic geometry and I am asking this because intuitively any two points are collinear but that also depends on our definition of "point"(Which I think in this case is a tuple of length $2$) and our definition of "line" and "lies on".  What are definitions of a "line" and "lies on" in $R^2$ that you say that a basis consists of two vectors/points that are not collinear?

Comment: @Seeker In geometry, a vector $\vec{AB}$ is a pair of points $(A,B)$ modulo the equivalence relation between pairs "can be translated to each other". This makes it possible to translate any vector to any pre-determined "origin" $O$. Vectors $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$ are collinear if the *three* points $O, A, B$ are collinear.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a basis of a vector space is: a set of vectors belonging to the space that satisfy the following: any vector in the space can be represented as a unique linear combination (not just "the sum", which is one specific linear combination) of the vectors in the basis.

The underlying notion is linear independence. In order to be a basis for a finite dimensional vector space, a set of vectors must 1) span the vector space (so that any vector can be represented as a linear combination) and 2) must be linearly independent (so that the linear combination is unique).

Often people assume that a basis has to be orthonormal (mutually perpendicular, unit length vectors), but that's not the case (although such a basis does make the math simpler in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

No, any two vectors are not always a basis. If you recall your definition of basis of a vector space from class, you will note that a set of vectors forms a basis if they possess two important properties:

- Linear independence
- They span the vector space

In the case of the XY plane, can you think of two vectors which violate one of these properties? Try starting with $\hat{i}$ and building another vector so that you still don't have a basis.